# Bind the pipe to stdin, there is a blocking problem

Tags: c

I want to associate the standard output of the parent process with the standard input of the child process through an anonymous pipe. I did achieve my needs, but I also encountered a problem: the program blocks when calling scanf, even if stdin is set to none Buffer, replace scanf with read to run normally! I know this has something to do with the standard I/O function buffer, but I don't know the internal reason, I hope I can get help, thank you!

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    int cpid;

    pipe(fd);

    if((cpid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(cpid == 0)
    {
        sleep(1);
        char buf[100] = {0};

        close(fd[1]);

        if(dup2(fd[0], 0) < 0)
        {
            perror("parent - dup2 error");
            exit(-1);
        }

        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        scanf("%s", buf);
        //read(0, buf, 100);

        printf("child: \n\t%s", buf);

        return 0;
    }

    sleep(1);
    close(fd[0]);

    if(dup2(fd[1], 1) < 0)
    {
        perror("parent - dup2 error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("123");

    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You added 3 specific versions of C++ standard but do not address any specific version in your question. You also don't address differences between C++ and C. Please do not add loads of different tags. That's considered spamming

Comment: Do not edit out `#include` directives or any other parts from your [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is something I really didn't think about as I just started using this forum. I'm really sorry to bother you, I will pay attention to it in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that to `scanf` to terminates its reading, necessitate that the data is *ended* in some way.

You are reading a string, but how scanf can know that there is nothing after 123? So it is waiting for something, either the end of communication, space, newlines, whatever can tell it that a string is fully available.

Try adding a simple spacing, a new line in the writing part:

```
printf("123 ");
```

or

```
printf("123\n");
```

Note that as is, you can not use the *closing* solution, just because you forgot to close the original descriptors after the dup.
Rewrite the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd[2];
    int cpid;

    pipe(fd);    
    if((cpid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if(cpid == 0) {
        sleep(1);
        char buf[100] = {0};    
        close(fd[1]);    
        if(dup2(fd[0], 0) < 0) {
            perror("parent - dup2 error");
            exit(-1);
        }
        close(fd[0]);  // close not useful original desriptor    
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        scanf("%s", buf);
        printf("child: \n\t%s", buf);    
        return 0;
    }

    sleep(1);
    close(fd[0]);    
    if(dup2(fd[1], 1) < 0) {
        perror("parent - dup2 error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    close(fd[1]); // close not useful original desriptor    
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("123");
    close(1); // close the "connexion" (ie the last open for writing descriptor on the pipe)    
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```